# ArcGIS Field Calculater DateAdd() gives Expected end of statement error

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, vbscript

I need to add seconds in an numeric column(TS_sec) to a datetime column(TS) in ArcGIS field calculator. I am using Vbscript.
But i am getting following error:
ERROR 999999: Error executing function. Expected end of statement Failed to execute (Calculate Field (16))

I am using following VBscript code:

```
Code block
----------------------------------------------------
dim TS_seconds as date
if [TS_sec] = Null then
TS_seconds=Null
else
TS_seconds=DateAdd ("s", [TS_sec] , [TS] )
end if
----------------------------------------------------
Expression ETA_TS=
TS_seconds
```

Answer (score 1):

When using VBScript, do not specify the variable type. Instead of

```
dim TS_seconds as date
```

simply use

```
dim TS_seconds
```